# Update from community to enterprise VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I currently have visual studio 2015 community edition installed on my system.Now i am thinking of upgrading to the `Enterprise` edition.As i have downloaded all required packages and programming languages in the previous community edition,is it possible to update this existing version to enterprise edition without having to download all the packages and programming languages again ?

Comment: All you can do is run the VS 2015 Enterprise installer and see if it needs to re-install those. It will either detect that they're fine and re-use them, or prompt you to install everything that you need for Enterprise. There's no way around what the installer chooses to do, though Microsoft has done a lot of work to make it pretty intelligent.

Comment: i did run it...however the installer doesn't provide options to download programming languages except for F# and python...does it mean that it has found out all the languages that are preinsalled and is not required to install again ?

Comment: That either means it doesn't need to install the others, or that it will install them and you can't opt-out. (F# and Python are definitely optional)

Comment: but c# and vb.net should be optional as well,what if i want to install any one of 'em ?? As far as i remember,the last time i installed vs,i had the option to choose between c# and vb.net and even both...but now i don't...feeilng a bit awkward :(

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx - the custom installations include everything from the Default installation, which is listed as "C#/VB, Web and Desktop Features"